# Состыковать две формы отправки сообщений

Tags: php, mysql

есть такой вопрос: хочу прикрутить корзину к мультиселлер магазинчику и нужно чтобы она отправляла заказ на емейл хозяина товара взятый из БД, а корзина отправляет на прописанный в ней вручную адрес.
Вот такой код, отправляет сообщение владельцу товара:

```
include '../include/config.php';
// Get seller email
$sqlSeller = "SELECT email FROM users WHERE id=" . $_REQUEST['sid'];

try{
    $query = $db->query($sqlSeller);

    $query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $row = $query->fetch();

    $to = $row['email'];

    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }

// Send email
$from = $_REQUEST['email'];
$subject = $_REQUEST['mtitle'];
$msg = $_REQUEST['msg'];
$header = "From: " . $_REQUEST['email'] . "\r\n";
mail($to, $subject, $msg, $header);


// Go to product edit page
$myUrl = "Location: ../product.php?id=" . $_REQUEST['pid'];
header($myUrl);
```

А это тот в котором нужно сделать отправку. Пытаюсь объединить вот так:

```
    <?php
parse_str($_POST['orderlist'], $orderlist);
parse_str($_POST['userdata'], $userdata);
/*
$orderlist - массив со списком заказа
$userdata - данные заказчика
*/
```

**Вместо вот этого. Начало**

```
    // ваш Email
$admin_mail = 'bosmasters352@gmail.com';
// Email заказчика (как fallback - ваш же Email)
$to = !empty($userdata['user_mail']) ? $userdata['user_mail'] : $admin_mail;
```

**Конец**

**Вставляю выборку из БД из первого кода. Начало**

```
$dbh = new \PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mschop', 'root', '');
$sqlSel = "SELECT email FROM users WHERE id=" . $_REQUEST['sid'];

try{
    $querySel = $db->query($sqlSel);

    $querySel->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $rowSel = $querySel->fetch();

    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
  $admin_mail = $rowSel['email'];
// Email заказчика (как fallback - ваш же Email)
$to = !empty($userdata['user_mail']) ? $userdata['user_mail'] : $admin_mail;
```

**Конец**

```
// Заголовок письма
$subject = 'Заказ от '.date('d.m.Y').'г.';

// Формируем таблицу с заказанными товарами
$tbl = '<table style="width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse;">
    <tr>
        <th style="width: 1%; border: 1px solid #333333; padding: 5px;">ID</th>
        <th style="width: 1%; border: 1px solid #333333; padding: 5px;"></th>
        <th style="border: 1px solid #333333; padding: 5px;">Наименование</th>
        <th style="border: 1px solid #333333; padding: 5px;">Цена</th>
        <th style="border: 1px solid #333333; padding: 5px;">Кол-во</th>
    </tr>';
$total_sum = 0;
foreach($orderlist as $id => $item_data) {
    $total_sum += (float)$item_data['count'] * (float)$item_data['price'];
    $tbl .= '
    <tr>
        <td style="border: 1px solid #333333; padding: 5px;">'.$item_data['id'].'</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid #333333;"><img src="'.$item_data['img'].'" alt="" style="max-width: 64px; max-height: 64px;"></td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid #333333; padding: 5px;">'.$item_data['title'].'</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid #333333; padding: 5px;">'.$item_data['price'].'</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid #333333; padding: 5px;">'.$item_data['count'].'</td>
    </tr>';
}
$tbl .= '<tr>
        <td  style="border: 1px solid #333333; padding: 5px;" colspan="3">Итого:</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid #333333; padding: 5px;"><b>'.$total_sum.'</b></td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid #333333;">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>';
// Тело письма
$body = '
<html>
<head>
  <title>'.$subject.'</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Информация о заказчике:</p>
    <ul>
        <li><b>Ф.И.О.:</b> '.$userdata['user_name'].'</li>
        <li><b>Тел.:</b> '.$userdata['user_phone'].'</li>
        <li><b>Email:</b> '.$userdata['user_mail'].'</li>
        <li><b>Адрес:</b> '.$userdata['user_address'].'</li>
        <li><b>Комментарий:</b> '.$userdata['user_comment'].'</li>
    </ul>
    <p>Информация о заказае:</p>
  '.$tbl.'
    <p>Письмо создано автоматически. Пожалуйста, не отвечайте на него, т.к. все ушли на пляж!</p>
</body>
</html>';

// Заголовки
$headers   = []; // или $headers = array() для версии ниже 5.4
$headers[] = 'MIME-Version: 1.0'; // Обязательный заголовок
$headers[] = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8'; // Обязательный заголовок. Кодировку изменить при необходимости
$headers[] = 'From: Best Shop <noreply@best-shop.piva.net>'; // От кого
$headers[] = 'Bcc: Admin <'.$admin_mail.'>'; // скрытая копия админу сайта, т.е. вам
$headers[] = 'X-Mailer: PHP/'.phpversion();
// Отправка
$send_ok = mail($to, $subject, $body, implode("\r\n", $headers));

// Ответ на запрос
$response = [
    'errors' => !$send_ok,
    'message' => $send_ok ? 'Заказ принят в обработку!' : 'Хьюстон! У нас проблемы!'
];
// ! Для версий PHP < 5.4 использовать традиционный синтаксис инициализации массивов:
/*
$response = array (
    'errors' => !$send_ok,
    'message' => $send_ok ? 'Заказ принят в обработку!' : 'Хьюстон! У нас проблемы!'
);
*/
exit( json_encode($response) );
```

Но ничего не выходит.Письмо не отправляется. Может подскажете в чем не состыковка и как исправить?

Comment: Для использования функции `mail` нужно настраивать сервер. Чтобы не настраивать сервер, лучше воспользоваться библиотекой типа **PHPMailer**

Answer (score 0):

Очень подозрительно выглядит данная строка, что у вас там в `$_POST['userdata']` лежит такое `parse_str($_POST['userdata'], $userdata);`?

```
var_dump ($_POST['userdata']);
var_dump ($userdata['user_mail']);
var_dump ($to);
```

Если предыдущие варианты не дадут результатов.
    `var_dump ($row);`

---

Ну и естественно мы надеемся, что сервер настроен под `smtp`.

Comment: Дело в том, что и первый код и второй сами по себе работают нормально. Но мне нужно их объединить так, что бы второй код отправлял заказ по адресу выбранному из БД как это делает первый. Во втором коде отредактировал поправки и изменения, так будет понятней что к чему.  Экспериментирую на Open Servere

Answer (score 0):

В целом разобрался. Все работает кроме главного - не срабатывает подстановка получателя
. $_REQUEST['sid'] Как же его подставить?